# drawing squares on canvas in foor loop only drawing one square

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am using the canvas element to draw white squares on a black canvas background.

I am having no difficulties drawing a black background, and can draw one star, however I am having difficulties drawing more than one white square. I am confused as I am drawing a new white star on each loop however, for some reason it is not drawing each star (white square).

[Based on this article I believe my code should work.](http://digitalarts.bgsu.edu/faculty/bonniem/Spring11/artc4330_1/notes/notes16.html)

Please see code below:

```
function Starfield () {
    this.ctx = document.getElementById('canvas');
    this.ctx = this.ctx.getContext("2d");
    this.stars = 2;
    this.createCanvas();
    this.createStar();
}

Starfield.prototype.createCanvas = function() {
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    this.ctx.fillRect(0,0, window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth );
};

Starfield.prototype.createStar = function() {
    var rand1 = Math.random() * 50;
    var rand2 = Math.random() * 50;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.stars; i++) {
        this.ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        this.ctx.fillRect(rand1, rand2, 2, 2);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below:

```
Starfield.prototype.createStar = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.stars; i++) {
        var rand1 = Math.random() * 50;
        var rand2 = Math.random() * 50;
        this.ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        this.ctx.fillRect(rand1, rand2, 2, 2);
    };
};
```

I moved the calls to `Math.random()` inside the loop. Your code was choosing just one location and drawing all the stars at that same location (on top of each other). You need a different random location for each star.

Comment: of course! makes sense, was drawing the same star in the same position! will give you the green mark when i can! thanks!